# How to sort by the number of likes over the last 30 days in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

First of all, I am coding in Kotlin.

I'd like to arrange the posts stored in the Realtime Database for a certain period of time based on the number of likes and display them in the RecyclerView.

my database structure

```
"posts": {
  "key": {
    "uid": "NHYVkW...",
    "title" : "Title",
    "time": "1666852764028",
    "like" : 2
  }
```

I've read about methods `orderByChild()`, `startAt()`, and `endAt()`, but I don't know how to use them in combination.

The examples I've seen set `startAt()` and `endAt()` for the key that enters `orderByChild()`.
But I want the sort to be based on like and the start and end points based on time.

Any examples I can refer to?
Please help.

Comment: So basically you want to filter the data based on two fields, right?

Comment: I want to filter data by time and sort by number of likes.

Comment: You can't use multiple `orderBy()` in same query. You can fetch all the posts in the date range and then sort based on likes on the client side. Also checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952747/firebase-multiple-where-clause-in-query?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: For your use-case, the best approach is to use the database to filter on the `time` and then re-order the results on `like` value in your application code.